# Notify user about my post

Tags: support

Assume I opened a post which I guess that there is an user which probably can answer and solve it.

1. How could I notify this user about my post?
2. Is it OK according to the Stack Exchange rules?

Comment: [Jon Skeet would love this feature. Not.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/08/22/stack-overflow-and-personal-emails.aspx) <--- this blog post kind of sums up exactly why this wouldn't be a nice feature.

Answer (score 6):

You don't summon user's to answer your post. Let them come to you. Notifying user's to answer questions would become quite annoying and abusive.

Comment: Exactly. Imagine how quickly people like Jon Skeet would simply leave the site!